# Open same modal window from different places on a HTML page without using id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on my first javascript project.

I am trying to open the same modal window and its contents from multiple places on an HTML page.

My code only works for the first button of the page and does not work with any other button on the same page. As you can see in my code below, I have already tried using `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementsById` but I am still facing issues. Is there a way to achieve this at all?

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Unrigged/acfjLgwx)

```
<button class="myBtn errormodalbutton">Open Modal 1</button>
<hr>
<button class="myBtn errormodalbutton">Open Modal 2</button>
<hr>
<button class="myBtn errormodalbutton">Open Modal 3</button>
<hr>
<button class="myBtn errormodalbutton">Open Modal 4</button>

<div class="myModal modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h3 style="text-align=center">Test</h3>
    <p>SOmetext.</p>
    <div class="close-button">
      <button type="button" class="right" onclick="closePopup()">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  font-style: normal;
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 0px 5px 10px;
  color: #333;
}


.errormodalbutton {
  background: none !important;
  border: none;
  padding: 0 !important;
  /*optional*/
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  /*input has OS specific font-family*/
  color: #069;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close-button {
  padding: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.close-button button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  float: right;
  font-style: normal;
  background: #6C757D;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```
 // Get the modal
 var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("myModal")[0];

 // Get the button that opens the modal
 var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn")[0];

 // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
 var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

 // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
 btn.onclick = function() {
   modal.style.display = "block";
 }

 // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
 span.onclick = function() {
   modal.style.display = "none";
 }

 // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
 window.onclick = function(event) {
   if (event.target == modal) {
     modal.style.display = "none";
   }
 }

 function closePopup() {
   modal.style.display = "none";
 }
```

Comment: you specifically in your code only allow one button with class `myBtn` to open the model ... `document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn")[0];` ... did you want the others to do so as well?

Comment: `var btns = [...document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn")];` and `btns.forEach(btn => btn.onclick = function() {
   modal.style.display = "block";
 });`

Comment: @JaromandaX - ah okay, so it would look like this?

```// Get the button that opens the modal
 var btns = [...document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn")];

 // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
 var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

 // When the user clicks the button, open the modal

 btns.forEach(btn => btn.onclick = function() {
   modal.style.display = "block";
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just update this 2 line**

```js
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn")[0];
```

with:

```js
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".myBtn");
```

And

```js
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

with:

```js
btns.forEach(btn => {
    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
    btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }
})
```

Here is the example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2t90k85/1/)

Comment: Please click the tick ✔️ @Dazzler